# How to rename glyph in a TrueType font using TTX/fontTools?

Tags: python, fonts, truetype

I am upgrading TrueType fonts with were created with a legacy codepage to create a Unicode counterparts. I am playing with Python TTX/fontTools but have not figured out a way to:
1. Rename the glyphs 
2. Merge the glyphs from two font file?

Can anyone please help?

P.S. I tried Robofab too, but got error when creating UFO files.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe these [blog entries by FontGeek](http://www.fontgeek.net/blog/?cat=7) can help you? Two of them are dealing with TTX/fontttools...

---

Basically, you need to do it in three steps:

1. Run `ttx` to convert the fontfile to an (editable) XML representation.
2. Do your edits in the XML file.
3. Run `ttx` again to convert the XML back to a valid fontfile.